# I want to do a search within an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with "databases" and inside them there is an array with objects ... I'm trying to search within those objects using his keywords and with that I get only 1 object return, I wanted to return all that contain the keyword

> search code

```js
Database.find({ 'data.words' : { "$in" : ["facebook"]}}, { 'data.$': 1, });
```

> An example of the data structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e331a85ec9a8548744899a9"),
    "uuid" : "XXXXX",
    "data" : [ 
            {
                    "words" : ["facebook"],
                    "status" : 0,
                    "uid" : "XXXXX",
                    "details" : {}
            },
            {
                "words" : ["youtube", "facebook"],
                "status" : 0,
                "uid" : "XXXXX",
                "details" : {}
        }
}
```

Comment: Not clear, which result do you expect. Please provide an example return document.

Comment: I want to receive all the objects within the array that contain that include as keywords...

Comment: so you want to receive a filtered result inside the returning document?

Comment: Maybe simply `find({ 'data.words' : "facebook"}, {  "data": 1})`?

Comment: Be best if you can include 3-4 top level objects that have their own "uuid" : "XXXXX" then illustrate with 2-3 examples what is the return object you want. Is it just uuid or inner arrays of matching or inner matching arrays along with the uuid?

Answer (score 0):

Document

```
 {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5e33fee6bc9987050fc40550"),
      "uuid" : "XXXXX",
      "data" : [ 
          {
              "words" : [ 
                  "facebook"
              ],
              "status" : 0,
              "uid" : "12345",
              "details" : {}
          }, 
          {
              "words" : [ 
                  "youtube", 
                  "facebook"
              ],
              "status" : 0,
              "uid" : "34567",
              "details" : {}
          }
      ]
  }
```

Query

```
 var wordsList = ["facebook"];

  db.collectionName.find({ 'data.words' : { "$in" : wordsList }})
       .map(function(list){
           var results = [];
           list.data.forEach(function (dataListElement){

               if(dataListElement.words.filter(value => wordsList.includes(value)).length > 0){
                   results.push(dataListElement);
               }
            })
           return results;
        }
   );
```

Result

```
  [
      [ 
          {
              "words" : [ 
                  "facebook"
              ],
              "status" : 0,
              "uid" : "12345",
              "details" : {}
          }, 
          {
              "words" : [ 
                  "youtube", 
                  "facebook"
              ],
              "status" : 0,
              "uid" : "34567",
              "details" : {}
          }
      ]
  ]
```